# Apilar cartas en una lista

Tags: python

El ejercicio me dice lo siguiente:

Crear una clase “pila_cartas” que vaya apilando las cartas una debajo de otra, pero sólo permita apilar en dos casos:

(i) si son de un número inmediatamente inferior y de diferente letra

(ii) si son de la misma letra. Si se intenta apilar una carta incorrecta, debe lanzar una excepción.

Yo ya tengo esto:

```
El Jugador 1 Tiene las siguientes cartas: ['12T', '5R', '6C', '11E', '10C', '2E', '3T', '11R', '2R', '12E']
El Jugador 2 Tiene las siguientes cartas: ['2T', '4T', '13T', '7T', '6T', '7R', '3C', '3R', '13R', '1R']
```

Mi pregunta es como podría apilarlos???

Pds: la primera carta se escoge aleatoriamente

Comment: Usa una lista, sus funciones y realiza las verificaciones correspondientes antes de agregar cartas.

Comment: Lo de "apilar" es una metáfora. En el fondo tienes una lista inicialmente vacía y conforme vas añadiendo elementos al final de la misma (con `.append()`) puedes imaginar que esa lista es una pila, cuyo último elemento es el último que has apilado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limitándolo a tu caso se podría resolver con algo similar a:

```
cartas = {
    1: ['12T', '5R', '6C', '11E', '10C', '2E', '3T', '11R', '2R', '12E'],
    2: ['2T', '4T', '13T', '7T', '6T', '7R', '3C', '3R', '13R', '1R']
}


turno = 1
pila = []

def apilar(t):
    while True:
        actual = pila[-1] if len(pila) > 0 else ''
        palo = actual[-1] if actual else False
        numero = actual[0:-1] if actual else False
        if len(cartas[t]) == 0:
            print('El jugador {} no tiene más cartas'.format(t))
            break
        carta_a_jugar = cartas[t][0]
        if carta_a_jugar[-1] == palo or carta_a_jugar[0:-1] == numero or not actual:
            pila.append(carta_a_jugar)
            cartas[t].pop(0)
        else:
            raise ValueError('No se puede jugar la carta {} del jugador {} sobre la carta {}'.format(
                carta_a_jugar, t, actual)
            )
        t = 2 if t == 1 else 1
```

---

Si quisiéramos una solución más versátil podemos construir todo el juego como una clase:

```
from random import shuffle


class Juego:
    def __init__(self, jugadores, numero_de_cartas, turno=1):
        self.jugadores = jugadores
        self.numero_de_cartas = numero_de_cartas
        self.palos = ['E', 'R', 'C', 'T']
        self.turno = turno
        self.cartas = {}
        self.baraja = []
        self.pila = []
        self.pasando = []

    def cambia_turno(self):
        self.turno = self.turno + 1 if self.turno < self.jugadores else 1

    def baraja_y_reparte(self):
        for palo in self.palos:
            self.baraja += [str(_) + palo for _ in range(1, 14)]

        shuffle(self.baraja)
        for i in range(0, self.jugadores):
            self.cartas[i + 1] = self.baraja[i:self.numero_de_cartas * self.jugadores:self.jugadores]

        self.baraja = self.baraja[self.numero_de_cartas * self.jugadores:]
        self.saca_carta()

    def saca_carta(self):
        if len(self.baraja) == 0:
            print('No quedan más cartas')
        self.pila.append(self.baraja.pop(0))
        self.pasando = []
        print('{} sacada del mazo'.format(self.pila[-1]))

    def jugar(self):
        self.baraja_y_reparte()
        while True:
            actual = self.pila[-1]
            palo = actual[-1]
            numero = actual[0:-1]
            carta_a_jugar = self.cartas[self.turno][0]

            if carta_a_jugar[-1] == palo or carta_a_jugar[0:-1] == numero:
                self.pila.append(self.cartas[self.turno].pop(0))
                self.pasando = []
                print('{} jugada por el jugador {}'.format(self.pila[-1], self.turno))

                if len(self.cartas[self.turno]) == 0:
                    print('El jugador {} no tiene más cartas y gana'.format(self.turno))
                    exit()
                self.cambia_turno()
            else:
                print('El jugador {} pasa'.format(self.turno))
                self.cambia_turno()
                if self.turno not in self.pasando:
                    self.pasando.append(self.turno)
                if len(self.pasando) == self.jugadores:
                    self.saca_carta()


juego = Juego(jugadores=3, numero_de_cartas=7, turno=1)
juego.jugar()
```

Answer (score -1):

En este código, la clase PilaCartas tiene un método apilar que verifica si se puede apilar una carta según las reglas que has mencionado: (i) si son de un número inmediatamente inferior y de diferente letra, o (ii) si son de la misma letra. Si se intenta apilar una carta que no cumple ninguna de estas condiciones, se lanzará una excepción de tipo ValueError. Puedes probar el código con el ejemplo proporcionado para ver cómo funciona o puedes dirigirte a nuestra [botanica chicago](https://elsecretoazteca.com/) y hablar con nuestros expertos en lectura de cartas.

class PilaCartas:
def **init**(self):
self.cartas = []

```
def apilar(self, carta):
    if not self.cartas:
        self.cartas.append(carta)
    else:
        carta_anterior = self.cartas[-1]
        if (carta_anterior.letra != carta.letra and
                carta_anterior.numero == carta.numero + 1):
            self.cartas.append(carta)
        elif carta_anterior.letra == carta.letra:
            self.cartas.append(carta)
        else:
            raise ValueError("No se puede apilar la carta.")
```

Comment: La pregunta considera número y letra en sus criterios. Tu respuesta trata las cartas como un simple valor entero. También tienes errores de sintaxis y falta una demo de que funcione. Llegastes y copiastes de chatGPT.